# How to perform image convolution on an image using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to perform edge detection for my images of soil grains using holistically nested edge detection method HED as shown however when using combined fine and coarse soil grains , the region of fine particles is not clear so I suggest making image convolution by cutting the image into smaller rectangular areas in both directions and make HED for every portion of image and store them to black copy image so as to add the edged portions to this image .

I faced an error after repeating the algorithm of HED in a for loop by dividing the width of image to 5 portions and the height to 4 portions but I can't fix that error .

Here is the algorithm used

```
# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import easygui

path = easygui.fileopenbox()
print(path)
hdir = os.path.dirname(path)
print(hdir)
hfilename = os.path.basename(path)
print(hfilename)
hname = os.path.splitext(hfilename)[0]
print(hname)
houtname = hname+"_out.jpg"
print(houtname)
hout = os.path.sep.join([hdir,houtname])
print(hout)

# # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
# ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ap.add_argument("-d", "--edge-detector", type=str, required=True,
#   help="path to OpenCV's deep learning edge detector")
# ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", type=str, required=True,
#   help="path to input image")
# args = vars(ap.parse_args())

class CropLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, params, blobs):
        # initialize our starting and ending (x, y)-coordinates of
        # the crop
        self.startX = 0
        self.startY = 0
        self.endX = 0
        self.endY = 0

    def getMemoryShapes(self, inputs):
        # the crop layer will receive two inputs -- we need to crop
        # the first input blob to match the shape of the second one,
        # keeping the batch size and number of channels
        (inputShape, targetShape) = (inputs[0], inputs[1])
        (batchSize, numChannels) = (inputShape[0], inputShape[1])
        (H, W) = (targetShape[2], targetShape[3])

        # compute the starting and ending crop coordinates
        self.startX = int((inputShape[3] - targetShape[3]) / 2)
        self.startY = int((inputShape[2] - targetShape[2]) / 2)
        self.endX = self.startX + W
        self.endY = self.startY + H

        # return the shape of the volume (we'll perform the actual
        # crop during the forward pass
        return [[batchSize, numChannels, H, W]]

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # use the derived (x, y)-coordinates to perform the crop
        return [inputs[0][:, :, self.startY:self.endY,
                self.startX:self.endX]]

# load our serialized edge detector from disk
print("[INFO] loading edge detector...")

fpath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
fdir =  os.path.dirname(fpath)
print(fdir)
protoPath = os.path.sep.join([fdir,"hed_model", "deploy.prototxt"])
print(protoPath)
modelPath =  os.path.sep.join([fdir,"hed_model","hed_pretrained_bsds.caffemodel"])
print(modelPath)

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, modelPath)

# register our new layer with the model
cv2.dnn_registerLayer("Crop", CropLayer)

# load the input image and grab its dimensions
image = cv2.imread('D:\My work\MASTERS WORK\GSD files\Sample E photos\SampleE_#1_26pxfor1mm.jpg')
im_copy = image.copy()*0
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]
# print(image.shape[:2])
# image.shape[:2] =(H*3, W*3)
# image = cv2.resize(image,0.5)
h=0
w=0
for m in range(0,H ,int(H/5)):
    for n in range(0,W,int(W/3)):
        gray = image[h:m,w:n]
        # convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and perform Canny
        # edge detection
        print("[INFO] performing Canny edge detection...")
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
        canny = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150)


        # construct a blob out of the input image for the Holistically-Nested
        # Edge Detector

        # cc = cv2.cvtColor(canny, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        # image = image+cc

        # mean = (104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434),

        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scalefactor=1.0, size=((m-h), (n-w)),
                                     # mean=(230, 120, 50),
                                     mean=(104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434),
                                     swapRB=False, crop=False)
        print( blob)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        # set the blob as the input to the network and perform a forward pass
        # to compute the edges
        print("[INFO] performing holistically-nested edge detection...")
        net.setInput(blob)
        hed = net.forward()
        hed = cv2.resize(hed[0, 0], ((m-h), (n-w)))
        hed = (255 * hed).astype("uint8")
        # Adding the edge detection for each portion to the copy image as follows
        im_copy = im_copy + hed
        h+=int(H/5)
        w+=int(W/4)
        # show the output edge detection results for Canny and
        # Holistically-Nested Edge Detection
        cv2.imshow("Input", image)
        cv2.imshow("Canny", canny)
        cv2.imshow("HED", hed)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow('Frame ',im_copy)
cv2.imwrite(hout, im_copy)
cv2v2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Here is one of soil particles images]

[image: and this is edge detection for original image .. my main issue is in the part of fine soil grains doesn't appear clearly as the coarse particles]

I then use this edged image in further analysis on the image .

The error I got using the algorithm

```
 net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, modelPath)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp:1121: error: (-2:Unspecified error) FAILED: fs.is_open(). Can't open "D:\My work\MASTERS WORK\hed_model\deploy.prototxt" in function 'cv::dnn::ReadProtoFromTextFile'
```